# Can't use virtualenv without sudo or user-specific install and reconfig

Tags: python, permissions, debian, virtualenv, pip

I would like to have a system-wide install of virtualenv on my debian jessie server, usable by each user without requiring sudo (the way it should work anyway) or user-specific installation.

Here's what I type from scratch:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3
#Install OK
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
#Install OK
$ pip3 install virtualenv
#Fails with "error: could not create '/usr/local/lib': Permission denied"
$ sudo pip3 install virtualenv
#Install OK, but it appears that '/usr/local/bin' now has 'drwxr-s---'
#permissions instead of 'drwxrwsr-x' (users can't list files in the directory...)
$ virtualenv env1
#Fails with "Command not found" (virtualenv is in '/usr/local/bin')
$ sudo virtualenv env1
#OK, but that's not the way it should work
```

I can get it to work with a user specific installation (`pip3 install --user virtualenv`) and some $PATH initialisation in "~/.bashrc" but it's a bit laborious for each user to have to install and reconfigure virtualenv.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but it seems pip3 is not setting the permissions properly on the files and folders it creates in '/usr/local' when I run the command to install virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

The problem was my '/etc/logins.def' file, in which I set the default UMASK for all users (including root) to 007 (no read/write/execute permission on new files or folders for non owner or non group members). So the line `sudo pip3 install virtualenv` was creating folders and executable files in '/usr/local' with too restrictive permissions.

To overcome this, I changed my root's umask in '/root/.bashrc' (in case someone uses `sudo su` to install a package) as well as added the following lines in '/etc/sudoers' via visudo:

```
#UMASK is not unioned with the one set in the PAM module
Defaults        umask_override
#Default UMASK is 007 for non-root users (for some reason I can't use 'Defaults>!root')
Defaults        umask=0007
#Root UMASK is 022, to overcome permission problems when installing packages
Defaults>root   umask=0022
```

Now I can execute virtualenv after repeating these steps:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3
#Install OK
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
#Install OK
$ sudo pip3 install virtualenv
#Install OK
$ virtualenv env1
#OK
```